# After putting deep linking with nested navigator, regular navigation does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My navigation scheme is:

```
const App = () => <AppNavigator />;

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  splash: SplashScreen,
  auth: () => <AuthStack uriPrefix={`${prefix}auth/`} />,
  main: () => <MainDrawer uriPrefix={`${prefix}main/`} />,
});

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  landing: LandingScreen,
  login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    path: 'login',
  },
  register: {
    screen: RegisterScreen,
    path: 'signup',
  },
});

const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStack,
    path: 'home',
  },
  Upsell: {
    screen: UpsellScreen,
    path: 'upsell',
  },
});
```

Using the above scheme, deep linking is working perfectly but regular navigation like going from `login` to `main` eg. `this.props.navigation.navigate('main')` is not working.

In `SpashScreen`, there are config data being downloaded and authorization checked which will prevent the user from going to `main` if failed.

I have identified the problem is with the `SwitchNavigator` and how `auth` and `main` are defined in it. Changing them to

```
auth: AuthStack,
main: MainDrawer,
```

makes regular navigation work but deep linking does not.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this issue? because I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try moving the `uriPrefix` to the root component separating the `main` and `auth` prefixes to the paths?

```js
const App = () => <AppNavigator uriPrefix={prefix} />;

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  splash: SplashScreen,
  auth: AuthStack,
  main: MainDrawer,
});

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  landing: LandingScreen,
  login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    path: 'auth/login',
  },
  register: {
    screen: RegisterScreen,
    path: 'auth/signup',
  },
});

const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStack,
    path: 'main/home',
  },
  Upsell: {
    screen: UpsellScreen,
    path: 'main/upsell',
  },
});
```

Comment: This will not work because in `SpashScreen`, there are config data being downloaded and authorization checked which will prevent the user from going to `main` if failed. This scheme goes to `splash` and then goes to `main` without waiting for the checks and configs.